# Gradient fill on the top surface of an annulus

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

Is it possible to use a gradient fill on the top surface of this annulus in matematica?

```
Graphics3D[
 ResourceFunction["Annulus3D"][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, {1, 3}]
]
```

I tried to use the Color function option but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: If you feel that the below answer solves your problem, make sure to accept it (click the checkmark). If not, leave a comment or edit your question to provide additional clarification.

Answer (score 10):

Something like this perhaps? This selects Hue based on angle:

```
n = 200;
s = Subdivide[n];
gOpts = {EdgeForm[], Hue[#], 
     ResourceFunction["Annulus3D"][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {1, 
       3}, {#*2 Pi, (# + 1/n)*2 Pi}]} & /@ Most[s];
Graphics3D[gOpts, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Another version with Hue based on radius:

```
n = 200;
maxR = 3;
rInner = 1;
s = Subdivide[rInner, maxR, n];
rescaled = Rescale[s];
gOpts = Table[{EdgeForm[], Hue[rescaled[[i]]], 
    ResourceFunction["Annulus3D"][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {s[[i - 1]],
       s[[i]]}]}, {i, 2, n}];
Graphics3D[gOpts, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

**Add-on**

As pointed out in a comment below, you may only want the top to be colored. I used an example under the styling section of the [Annulus3D documentation](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Annulus3D/) to just color the top surface (the top, bottom, and inner and outer radius are the first four elements of an `Annulus3D` object it looks like). This is a pretty ugly implementation so you can likely make it easier to read:

```
n = 200;
s = Subdivide[n];
gOpts = Flatten[
   Table[{baseL, baseH, circumIn, circumOut} = 
     ResourceFunction["Annulus3D"][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {1, 
        3}, {i*2 Pi, (i + 1/n)*2 Pi}][[1 ;; 4]];
    {{EdgeForm[], Hue[i], baseH}, {EdgeForm[], Black, 
      baseL}, {EdgeForm[], Black, circumIn}, {EdgeForm[] , Black, 
      circumOut}}, {i, Most[s]}], 1];
Graphics3D[gOpts, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: @infinitezero thanks for pointing this out. I added another example, though the code for it can probably be improved